# Find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $|5^x - 2^y| = 1$.

Tags: number-theory, integers

> Find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $$\large |5^x - 2^y| = 1$$

Below is a graph of the equation $|5^x - 2^y| = 1$. As can clearly be seen, $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$ are the solutions. I don't know the other answers, maybe there could be none.
[image]

Comment: Do you need an elementary solution? Because otherwise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$5^x - 2^y = 1$$

If $y=1$, then there is no integer $x$ such that $5^x=3$.

If $y=2$, then $5^x=5$ implies $x=1$.

If $y\ge 3$, then$$5^x\equiv 1\pmod 8$$
So, we see that $x$ has to be even.

Then, we have
$$1-(-1)^y\equiv 1\pmod 3\implies (-1)^y\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
which is impossible.

---

$$5^x - 2^y = -1$$

If $y=1$, then there is no integer $x$ such that $5^x=1$.

If $y=2$, then there is no integer $x$ such that $5^x=3$.

If $y\ge 3$, then we get $$5^x\equiv 7\pmod 8$$which is impossible.

---

Therefore, the only solution for $$|5^x-2^y|=1$$
is $(x,y)=(1,2)$.